# Running delayed_job as a windows service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-services, delayed-job

I am trying to get delayed_job working as a windows service.

I am so thoroughly sick of windows I can't even begin to put it into words, but I am stuck with it for now due to 3rd party dependencies.

Running `rake jobs:work` starts the worker in a console with no problems.

I've created an empty windows service to start and shutdown the worker using `sc create DelayedJobWorker...`.

However, I can't get the service to start and stop the worker. I'm not sure what the best approach is - what I should be parameterising the service with / asking it to call.

Any suggestions gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did this by:

1. Copying srvany.exe from the [Windows Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657) to `C:\windows\system32`.
2. Creating an empty service using `sc create JobQueue binPath= "C:\windows\system32"`
3. Adding a registry key called `Parameters` to the service registry key located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > services > JobQueue`
4. Adding the following three string values to the new registry key.

As below:

```
Application="c:\ruby193\bin\ruby.exe"
AppDirectory="$PATH_TO_RAILS_APP"
AppParameters="c:\ruby193\bin\rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=$ENVIRONMENT"
```

Comment: You said adding "four string values" but I only see 3.

Comment: Haha,, that is not my point.  I tried the instructions, but the service failed to start.  I thought you missed a parameter.  Does PATH_TO_RAILS_APP resolve to the base directory?

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to replace $PATH_TO_RAILS_APP and $ENVIRONMENT with the actual path to your rails app and the environment you want it to run in.