# Is it possible to create delayed_job as windows service using mongrel?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, delayed-job

I am working on Rails 2 and ruby version 1.8.7 (RoR web application with mySQL)in Windows OS. The delayed_job works fine as long as I type rake jobs:work into the command prompt and let the console to remain open. I would like to make it run at the background as soon as the computer start up/reboot.

I've found some solutions here too, by using srvany.exe and tweaking the registry(which I dislike tempering with registry) and also by adding an "&" at the end of the rake command.

I wonder if I can create delayed_job windows service just by typing something like this:

mongrel_rails service::install -N servicename -c c:\programname\delayed_job -e development

Please correct me if I'm wrong. But is it possible to create delayed_job as windows service using mongrel? I am interested in this method because it is simpler (and do not need to concern about tweaking the registry). Some tips to do it if possible. If not,can you recommend other methods?

thanks from a RoR noob.

Comment: Just guessing. I guess you can create a batch file with the jobs:work command and execute it with start up right ?

Comment: @0v3rc10ck3d yup, successfully created the window service using the srvany.exe but delayed_job become extremely slow i.e.fails to display the job queued.

Answer (score 0):

As overclocked suggested previously I created a batch file for the rails application. Because the application is a third party software, I simply added these 2 lines into a batch file.

Open notepad 
type these 2 lines:-

cd c:\application name

rake jobs:work

save as .bat format

Another solution is to add the command manually.

The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386825/running-delayed-job-as-a-windows-service) except that we should type "sc create JobQueue binPath= "C:\windows\system32\srvany.exe" instead of "sc create JobQueue binPath= "C:\windows\system32"