# Is there is something like cron in rails application on windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm trying to use `cron` in my application to send mails every week but I think it doesn't work on Windows.

Does anybody knows any equivalent to `cron` solution that works on Windows?

Comment: On Windows, you'd use the [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614.aspx). Doesn't look like it's being actively developed, but maybe the [win32-taskscheduler](https://rubygems.org/gems/win32-taskscheduler/) gem is of any help to you.

Comment: how to use win32-taskscheduler ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows equivalent of Unix's `cron` is a "Task Scheduler". You can configure your periodical task there.

[image]

## Purely Ruby solution

If you want a purely Ruby solution look into:

- [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) - it's Windows cron gem.
- [crono](https://github.com/plashchynski/crono) - it's a in-Rails cron scheduler, so it should work anywhere.
- [Web services](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20web%20cron) - there are plenty of free online services that would make a request to a given URL in specific time periods. This is basically a poor man's cronjob.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) and the extension [Resque-scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler) gems. You will need to have a resque scheduler process running with `bundle exec rake resque:scheduler` and at least one worker process running with `QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work`.
If you want these services to run in the background as a windows service, you can do it with `srvany.exe` as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386825/running-delayed-job-as-a-windows-service).

The above assumes you are ok with installing Redis - a key-value store that is very popular among the Rails community as it can be easily used to support other Rails components such as caching and ActionCable, and it is awesome by itself for many multi-process use cases.

Resque is a queue system on top of Redis that allows you to define jobs that can be executed asynchronously in the background. When you run `QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work`, a worker process runs constantly and polls the queue. Once a job is enqueued, an available worker pops it from the queue and starts working on it. This architecture is quite scalable, as you can have multiple workers listening to the queues if you'd like.

To define a job, you do this:

```
class MyWeeklyEmailSenderJob
  def self.perform
    # Your code to send weekly emails
  end
end
```

While you can enqueue this job to the queue yourself from anywhere (e.g. from a controller as a response to an action), in your case you want it to automatically be placed into the queue once a week. This is what Resque-scheduler is for. It allows you to configure a file such as `app/config/resque_schedule.yml` in which you can define which jobs should be enqueued in which time interval. For example:

```
send_weekly_emails:
  cron: 0 8 * * Mon
  class: MyWeeklyEmailSenderJob
  queue: email_sender_queue
  description: "Send weekly emails"
```

Remember that a scheduling process has to run in order for this to work with `bundle exec rake resque:scheduler`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys , actually i tried rufus scheduler gem and it worked for me , i guess it's the best and easier solution